# Unexpected duplication of form output

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm currently making a program for my players in an RPG to be able to select their character skills from drop-down menus which will 1. Display the title of the skill under the results section and also in the Selected Advantages section(top right). 2. Display the description of the skill under its title.

It is working mostly as intended except for a bug I have discovered. I can select the desired advantage and it will appear as expected. It will also remove the selection when I click on the delete button under the Selected Advantages section at the top right of the page.

The problem is that if I reselect the same advantage it will display the advantage description twice at the bottom of the page, if I do the same again it will display three times, and so on.

When I delete a selection the container is removed but when they are selected again the subsequent descriptions are also contained in a single container instead of creating a new one.

Here is my code so far.
Note: I have only included the object for Absolute Direction but have tested with others and get the same duplication result.

```js
const createDivElement = document.createElement('div');

//Creates containers for the selected advantage descriptions.
function createContainer(advantageName) {
  const placeAdvantageDescription = document.getElementById('place-text');
  placeAdvantageDescription.appendChild(createDivElement);
  createDivElement.setAttribute("id", `container-${advantageName}`);
}
//Creates and adds the text for the selected advantages title, points and description.
//should I make this three seperate functions???
function addAdvantageText(advantageObject) {
  const createTitleElement = document.createElement('p');
  const createPointsElement = document.createElement('p');
  const createDescriptionElement = document.createElement('p');
  //creates Title
  createDivElement.append(createTitleElement);
  createTitleElement.classList.add("title");
  createTitleElement.innerText = advantageObject.title;
  //creates points
  createDivElement.append(createPointsElement);
  createPointsElement.classList.add("points");
  createPointsElement.innerText = `${advantageObject.points}.`;
  //creates description
  createDivElement.append(createDescriptionElement);
  createDescriptionElement.classList.add("description-text");
  createDescriptionElement.innerHTML = advantageObject.description;
}
//creates sub catagories for selected advantage and adds the extra text if applicable.
function addSubCategories(advantageObject) {
  if (advantageObject.subCategory1) {
    let createSubCategory1 = document.createElement('p');
    createDivElement.append(createSubCategory1);
    createSubCategory1.innerHTML = `<strong>${advantageObject.subCategory1.name}:</strong> ${advantageObject.subCategory1.text}<br><strong><em>${advantageObject.subCategory1.sub1Points}</em></strong>.`;
  }
  if (advantageObject.subCategory2) {
    let createSubCategory2 = document.createElement('p');
    createDivElement.append(createSubCategory2);
    createSubCategory2.innerHTML = `<strong>${advantageObject.subCategory2.name}:</strong> ${advantageObject.subCategory2.text}<br><strong><em>${advantageObject.subCategory2.sub2Points}</em></strong>.`;
  }
  if (advantageObject.subCategory3) {
    let createSubCategory3 = document.createElement('p');
    createDivElement.append(createSubCategory3);
    createSubCategory3.innerHTML = `<strong>${advantageObject.subCategory3.name}:</strong> ${advantageObject.subCategory3.text}<br><strong><em>${advantageObject.subCategory3.sub3Points}</em></strong>.`;
  }
  if (advantageObject.subCategory4) {
    let createSubCategory4 = document.createElement('p');
    createDivElement.append(createSubCategory4);
    createSubCategory4.innerHTML = `<strong>${advantageObject.subCategory4.name}:</strong> ${advantageObject.subCategory4.text}<br><strong><em>${advantageObject.subCategory4.sub4Points}</em></strong>.`;
  }
  if (advantageObject.extraText) {
    let createExtraText = document.createElement('p');
    createDivElement.appendChild(createExtraText);
    createExtraText.innerHTML = advantageObject.extraText;
  }
}
//adds name of chosen advantages in Selected Advantages column and a delete button for each.
function addToSelectedColumn(advantageName) {
  const hr = document.createElement('hr');
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  const createSelectedAdvantageDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const placeSelectedText = document.getElementById('selected-items');

  placeSelectedText.appendChild(createSelectedAdvantageDiv);
  createSelectedAdvantageDiv.append(advantageName.toUpperCase());
  createSelectedAdvantageDiv.setAttribute("id", `selected-items-container-${advantageName}`);
  createSelectedAdvantageDiv.append(button);
  button.setAttribute("id", `delete-${advantageName}`);
  createSelectedAdvantageDiv.append(hr);
}

function removeAdvantageText(removeThis) {
  let advantageDescriptionToRemove = document.getElementById(`container-${removeThis}`);
  let selectedAdvantageToRemove = document.getElementById(`selected-items-container-${removeThis}`);
  advantageDescriptionToRemove.remove();
  selectedAdvantageToRemove.remove();
}

function removeAdvantage(advantageToDelete) {
  document.getElementById(`delete-${advantageToDelete}`).addEventListener("click", function() {
    removeAdvantageText(advantageToDelete);
  })
};

function addAdvantage(advantageInString, advantageObjectName) {
  createContainer(advantageInString);
  addToSelectedColumn(advantageInString);
  addAdvantageText(advantageObjectName);
  addSubCategories(advantageObjectName);
}

//Event listeners for when users select advantage. They will check for matching selection then call addAdvantage() with arguments.

//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
document.getElementById("submit-advantage-a").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const userAdvantageA = document.getElementById('user-advantages-a').value;

  if (userAdvantageA === 'absolute direction') {
    addAdvantage('absolute direction', absoluteDirection);
    removeAdvantage('absolute direction');
  } else if (userAdvantageA === 'absolute timing') {
    addAdvantage('absolute timing', absoluteTiming);
    removeAdvantage('absolute timing');
  } else if (userAdvantageA === 'acute senses') {
    addAdvantage('acute senses', acuteSenses);
    removeAdvantage('acute senses');
  }
});

let absoluteDirection = {
  title: "Absolute Direction",
  points: "5 or 10 points",
  description: "You have an excellent sense of direction.This ability comes in two levels:",
  subCategory1: {
    name: "Absolute Direction",
    text: "You always know which way is north, and you can always retrace a path you have followed within the past month, no matter how faint or confusing. This ability does not work in environments such as interstellar space or the limbo of the astral plane, but it does work underground, underwater, and on other planets. This gives +3 to Body Sense and Navigation (Air, Land, or Sea).<br> (Note: The navigational sense that guides migratory creatures to their destination is too crude to qualify; treat it as a 0-point feature.)",
    sub1Points: "5 points"
  },
  subCategory2: {
    name: "3D Spatial Sense",
    text: "As above, but works in three dimensions. This ability is useful in deep space – although it does not help you if you travel across dimensions. You get the skill bonuses to Piloting and +2 to Aerobatics, Free Fall, and Navigation (Hyperspace or Space).",
    sub2Points: "10 points"
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
}

.points {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#selected-items-container {
  float: right;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20rem;
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

.forms {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js" async></script>
  <title>GCRC</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="home-nav" href="*">Home</a>
  <div class="make-choice">
    <div id="selected-items-container"><strong>SELECTED ADVANTAGES</strong>
      <hr>
      <div id="selected-items"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="forms">
      <h1>Select your characters advantages</h1>
      <p>A.</p>
      <form method="GET">
        <select name="user-advantages-a" id="user-advantages-a">
          <option value="absolute direction">Absolute Direction</option>
          <option value="absolute timing">Absolute Timing</option>
          <option value="acute senses">Acute Senses</option>
        </select>
        <input id="submit-advantage-a" type="submit" />
      </form>
      <p>B.</p>
      <form method="GET">
        <select name="user-advantages-b" id="user-advantages-b">
          <option value="binding">Binding</option>
          <option value="blessed">Blessed</option>
          <option value="brachiator">Brachiator</option>
        </select>
        <input id="submit-advantage-b" type="submit" />
      </form>
      <p>C.</p>
      <form method="GET">
        <select name="user-advantages-c" id="user-advantages-c">
          <option value="catfall">Catfall</option>
          <option value="chameleon">Chameleon</option>
          <option value="channeling">Channeling</option>
        </select>
        <input id="submit-advantage-c" type="submit" />
      </form>
      <p>D.</p>
      <form method="GET">
        <select name="user-advantages-d" id="user-advantages-d">
          <option value="damage resistance">Damage Resistance</option>
          <option value="danger sense">Danger Sense</option>
          <option value="daredevil">Daredevil</option>
        </select>
        <input id="submit-advantage-d" type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="display-choice">
    <p>Advantages</p>
    <div class="advantages">
      <div id="place-text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's what `append` and `appendChild` do, they append content to the exisiting content. You've to empty the element before appending new content to it.